# PHP: accessing sequentially numbered POST entries

Tags: php, post

I'm going to have html form that is going to send out chunks of text labeled 'chunk1', 'chunk2', 'chunk3' up to a potentially unknown number. Is there a way to sequentially go through $_POST['chunk1'] and so on until one isn't set?
I could do a foreach but the foreach is going to contain other POST values too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about:

```
for ( $i=1 ; isset($_POST['chunk'.$i]) ; $i++) {
  // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Make sure you start `$i` at 1, given the OP mentions the post variables start with "chunk1".

Comment: I think this is the way I should go. Thanks a lot. Cant believe I didn't think of this though haha.

Answer (score 3):

just use

```
<input name="chunk[0]">
<input name="chunk[1]">
...
```

and in PHP then

```
$_POST['chunk'][$i] ....
```

Comment: unfortunately the input names are outside of my control.

Answer (score 0):

Just do your foreach, and check each key entry to make sure it starts with `'chunk'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if (strstr($key,"chunk") === false) continue;
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: What if OP has both `<input name="chunk1" />` _and_ `<input name="chunks" value="1" />`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$chunks = preg_grep('/^chunk\d+$/', array_keys($_POST));
```

this'll return an array of just the POST entries that are chunk1, chunk2, etc...

Comment: Doesn't [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) match _values_ not _keys_? ([example given](http://www.ideone.com/uv555))